# where to get this reference about Kalman filter, technical report

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, kalman-filter

I'm sorry for this question that might not fit in here however, I would like to give it a shot. I've chosen this stack since the question is somehow related to mobile robots. I've came across a paper in Mobile Robot Localization that has cited the following reference,

> C. Brown, H. Durrant-Whyte, J. Leonard, B. Rao, and B. Steer.  Kalman
>   filter algorithms, applications, and utilities. Technical Report
>   OUEL-1765/89, Oxford U. Robotics Research Group, 1989.

I couldn't find this reference. Nothing show up in Google not even in Google Scholar. In my university which allows me to access to a massive database, also nothing show up. Since this is a technical report, I'm interested to read it to have more appreciation about Kalman Filter. Has anyone came across this reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the named researchers is still at that Oxford University group, it can be reasonable to write/email to the researcher explaining your interest and ask if it is possible to obtain a copy - even though it's old. Or if you're shy ask your supervisor if this would be a good idea first.

However it is a very general sounding title, it's possible it doesn't have the precise thing that you're looking for... and many things have been written on the subject since.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Croco I disagree - this **is** the answer. Write the people that wrote the report, or write Oxford. The paper was written before the Internet was a big deal, so it probably exists in hard copy there and just hasn't been scanned.